# How can I print the path between two nodes of a tree (graph) using stack data structure?

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, stack, traversal

I have approached it this way:

suppose the nodes are A and B.

start from node A
if node is unvisited, then push it into the stack.
move onto its children.
if we backtrack from any node then pop it from the stack.

continue it until you reach B and then print the stack

Comment: It seems that you have the skeleton of your algorithm right. What step is blocking you ?

Comment: I don't know how to implement this code in java. Basically I am not able to decide when to pop the element and at what condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code that will allow to find a path (any path, not the shortest) between two nodes of a graph if such a path exist

```
function find_path(G):
    s = init_stack()
    visited_vertices = set()
    stack.push(A)
    return rec_function(s, B, visited_vertices)

function rec_function(s, B, visited_vertices):
    A = stack.head
    if visited_vertices.contains(A) then:
        return false
    if A == B then:
        print_stack(s)
        return true
    for C in A.children do:
        s.push(C)
        found_dest = rec_function(s, B)
        if found_dest then: 
            return true
    s.pop()
    return false
```

It is not written in a very intuitive manner, since usually we will take advantage of the fact that we use a recursive function to 'hide' the stack within the recursive calls stack.
In order to understand how this code runs, you can take a small example, with a few vertices in the graph (say 5) and run it by hand.